# AWS ECS Fargate scheduled task doesn't seem to be using capacity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've had a scheduled task running that triggers every 10 minutes. I wanted to increase this to every 5 minutes and change the provider balancing to use spot instances so I set the clusters default capacity provider strategy weight for spot to 4 and on-demand to 1.

But I don't think this is actually doing anything. When I look at the task information the capacity provider is blank which leads me to believe spot is not being used (image below).

[image]

I found a [thread](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/937) from a few years ago of people asking for this which has since been closed. It ends with a link to [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-ecs-supports-additional-configurations-for-scheduled-and-event-driven-tasks/) that seems to say that it should be available for "ECS Tasks that run on a periodic or scheduled basis" but then it goes on to mostly talk about tasks which are scheduled in eventbridge.

Anyone have any advice on this?

Edit: I just read this (emphasis mine) in the Default capacity provider strategy:

> The default capacity provider strategy is used when **creating a service or running a standalone task** in the cluster and whenever a custom capacity provider strategy or a launch type isn't specified.

So I guess this just still doesn't exist all these years later. That's a shame

Comment: You haven't provided any information about your task nor service definition.

Comment: I didn't provide more than what I wrote here because they did not seem relevant. The task is a simple image that gets instantiated using fargate every 10 minutes and runs a script. The service is more or less the default settings with some permission adjustments and the changes I mentioned to the default capacity provider strategy. This was a general question about "scheduled tasks", the ones you can set up within the service, and I wanted to know, "is this possible?" since I can't find any documentation on this. From what I can tell though the answer is no and I'm using EventBridge now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason you can't set the compute options from within the service created "scheduled tasks". But it can be done in EventBridge after the scheduled task has been created by following these steps:

1. EventBridge
2. Rules
3. [name of rule]
4. Edit
5. Step 3 Select Targets
6. Compute Options
7. Use Cluster Default